# Different image resolution in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, modern-document-library, image-rendition

I have a requirement - When user uploads images to SharePoint they would like the images to have a low/med/high resolution for each of the images.

They don't want to upload individual images with different resolution.
When the images needs to be downloaded the would want to have the option where users can choose to download any of the three

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, SharePoint already generates thumbnails in different resolutions. You can build URL with [REST API](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/document-thumbnail-via-rest-api-sharepoint-framework) for example. But in your case, it's simpler, you can use column formatting to display links to help users downloading the thumbnail as there are built-in properties with the thumbnails URL (`@thumbnail.small`, `@thumbnail.medium`, `@thumbnail.large`).

Step by step:

- Open a view of your document library
- Create a new text column
- Click on the column header > Column settings > Format this column
- Copy/paste the JSON
- Preview and save

  ```
  {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "Small",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "@thumbnail.small"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": " | "
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "Medium",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "@thumbnail.medium"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": " | "
    },
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "Large",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "@thumbnail.large"
      }
    }
  ]}
  ```

[image: create a new column]
[image: format the column]
[image: json formatting]
[image: thumbnails]

If you want to **display** thumbnails as images, and not generate links, you can also use this formatting:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "img",
  "attributes": {
    "src": "@thumbnail.medium"
  },
  "style": {
    "display": "block",
    "margin": "0 auto",
    "max-height": "42px"
  }
}
```

Or, with the `getpreview` handler:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "img",
  "attributes": {
  "src": {
    "operator": "+",
    "operands": [
      "/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?path=",
      "[$FileRef]",
      "&resolution=1"
    ]
  }
  },
  "style": {
    "display": "block",
    "margin": "0 auto"
  }
}
```

[image: display thumbnail]

Comment: Thanks jleture for the detailed info and i also found out you could also use other url. Will give this a shot and let you know

Comment: Hi jleture, After giving it a go. The url is howing the same image size. Any reason why?

Comment: Try with a large image? During my test, I really had small, medium and large thumbnails.

Comment: Thanks I changed the image and that works, Question  though how can i have the same links but in a Gallery(Document Card View).
I tried it but its not the image in a different resolution

Comment: The default `Tiles` view will display the thumbnail if available. You can also edit this view formatting with JSON or use the `getThumbnailImage` function to generate thumbnail URL.

Comment: Hi jleture, Thanks for the response. Its not the issue with the Thumbnail image , i can see the image in the Tile view. I would like to display the small, Medium and Large links as you advised in my original post. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Small, medium and large are thumbnails and can be displayed as images (but your original question is about to downloard, not display). You have to use JSON formatting with `"elemtype" : "img"` and `"src":` with `@thumbnail.medium`or `getThumbnailImage([$Your-Image-Field-Name], 400, 200)`

Comment: Thanks jleture. I would give that a shot.I currently use the below
https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/getpreview.ashx?path={pathToTheDocument}&resolution=1
in the list viewand it works my question is should the same work for Tile/Document Card view? I tried but it doesn't

Comment: Maybe you should create a new question because no one will read comments here. Does my answer is correct regarding your original question? Please accept it, or down vote if you are not satisfied.

Comment: You answered my question jleture. I was just wanted the same solution but on a Tile view thats it

Comment: Thanks. Yes you can, even in the tiles view. You have to change the `url` with a concatenation to recreate the URL (`[$FileRef]` is the URL of your file). I edited my answer.